# SQLite3 field names not recognized by PHP in result set associative array

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

When I retrieve a row from a SQLite3 database, using the default `fetch()` mode of both associative and numeric indexes, the numeric index works but I get "undefined index" if I try to use the associative one. That is,

```
$timeReadBack = $resultArray2[0];
```

gives the correct result, but

```
$timeReadBack = $resultArray2['startTime'];
```

gives "undefined index".

And I'm *positive* I have the field name correct.

Here's the whole sequence:

```
$result2 = $db->prepare( 'SELECT parameterValue FROM CurrentState WHERE parameterName = ?;' );
$result2->bindValue(1,'startTime');
$selectStatement = $result2->execute();
$resultArray2 = $result2->fetch();
$timeReadBack = $resultArray2[0];
```

`parameterName` and `parameterValue` are TEXT fields in the table.

Comment: **Debugging hint**  Add a `var_dump($resultArray2)` and see exactly what is in that array!

Comment: It would also help if you showed us the query that populates `$resultArray2` That would save us having to play 20 questions with you to get all the relevant information. See [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Not to mention the code that you're using to fetch the result.

Comment: Using default fetch() defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. The field names are case sensitive. Also check the SQL query if `startTime` is part of the select fields.

Comment: code added to question

Comment: GOOD EVANS!!!! `SELECT parameterValue FROM` will return a resultset containing ONLY the `parameterValue` column ... So PHP is correct **there is no `startTime` column in the resultset**

Comment: Bingo! I should have asked for `$resultArray2["parameterValue"]`. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SELECT does not contain a field named startTime. So, the `$resultArray2` will only contain keys from the SELECT fields (only `parameterValue`).

`SELECT parameterValue FROM CurrentState WHERE parameterName = ?`

Also, you are using `startTime` to bind a parameter. It means that `startTime` is a value, not a field name. So, you cannot access the column by the value, only for the field name `parameterValue`

```
$result2 = $db->prepare( 'SELECT parameterValue FROM CurrentState WHERE parameterName = ?;' );
$result2->bindValue(1,'startTime');
$selectStatement = $result2->execute();
$resultArray2 = $result2->fetch();
$timeReadBack = $resultArray2[0];
$timeReadBack = $resultArray2['parameterValue']; // 'startTime' is a value
```